# Undefined reference to extern function - C

Tags: c, include, extern, undefined-reference

I'm currently working on a C project, but I'm stuck on what seems to be a simple problem...

My files are **main.c**, **main.h**, **fun1.c**, **fun2.c** and **fun3.c**.

**main.h** is included in **main.c**, fun1, fun2 and fun3 (respectively in **fun1.C**, **fun2.c** and **fun3.c** files) are used by a function in **main.c**, and the fun1, fun2 and fun3 functions are declared in **main.h** like that:

```
extern int fun1(unsigned);
extern int fun2(int, int, int);
extern int fun3(int, int);
```

But when I try to compile the code, I get these errors

```
main.c:12: undefined reference to 'fun1'
main.c:17: undefined reference to 'fun2'
main.c:25: undefined reference to 'fun3'
```

Did I miss something about the way `extern` works? Thanks for your answers.

The project is actually a lot more complex since I am working on a kernel, but I simplified it. This is a work that my teacher gave me, and I'm trying to modify the code as less as possible, that's why I'm sticking to the use of `extern`.

---

***UPDATE***

As the problem seems to lie somewhere else, I'm going to show you my file system.

My files are **sem.c**, **sem.h**, **semget.c**, **semctl.c** and **semop.c**.

**sem.h** is included in **sem.c**, semget, semctl and semop (respectively in **semget.C**, **semctl.c** and **semop.c** files) are used by a function in **sem.c**, and the semget, semctl and semop functions are declared as extern in **sem.h** (same as before, just changed back the names).

At some point in the makefile (don't ask me what the makefile is doing, I have no idea because of its complexity), the file **syscalls.c** is used:

```
#include <nanvix/const.h>
#include <nanvix/syscall.h>

/*
 * System calls table.
 */
PUBLIC void (*syscalls_table[NR_SYSCALLS])(void)  = {
    (void (*)(void))&sys_alarm,
    ...
    (void (*)(void))&semget,
    (void (*)(void))&semctl,
    (void (*)(void))&semop
};
```

The **syscalls.c** file include the **syscall.h** file:

```
#ifndef NANVIX_SYSCALL_H_
#define NANVIX_SYSCALL_H_

#include <nanvix/const.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <ustat.h>
#include <utime.h>

/* Number of system calls. */
#define NR_SYSCALLS 51

/* System call numbers. */
#define NR_alarm 0
#define NR_brk 1
...
#define NR_semget 48
#define NR_semctl 49
#define NR_semop 50

#ifndef _ASM_FILE_

/* System calls prototypes. */
EXTERN unsigned sys_alarm(unsigned seconds);
EXTERN int sys_brk(void *ptr);
...
EXTERN int semget(unsigned key);
EXTERN int semctl(int semid, int cmd, int val);
EXTERN int semop(int semid, int op);

#endif /* _ASM_FILE_ */
#endif /* NANVIX_SYSCALL_H_ */
```

The exact error is what follows:

```
sys/syscalls.o:(.data+0xc0): undefined reference to `semget'
sys/syscalls.o:(.data+0xc4): undefined reference to `semctl'
sys/syscalls.o:(.data+0xc8): undefined reference to `semop'
sys/sem.o: In function `create':
/home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/src/kernel/sys/sem.c:12: undefined reference to `semget'
/home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/src/kernel/sys/sem.c:17: undefined reference to `semctl'
sys/sem.o: In function `down':
/home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/src/kernel/sys/sem.c:25: undefined reference to `semop'
sys/sem.o: In function `up':
/home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/src/kernel/sys/sem.c:33: undefined reference to `semop'
sys/sem.o: In function `destroy':
/home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/src/kernel/sys/sem.c:41: undefined reference to `semctl'
makefile:67: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
```

And finally, the last command line executed by `make` before the error was:

```
i386-elf-ld -T arch/x86/link.ld arch/x86/utilities.o arch/x86/io.o arch/x86/boot.o arch/x86/hooks.o arch/x86/setup.o arch/x86/hwint.o arch/x86/8259.o arch/x86/exception.o arch/x86/clock.o arch/x86/hal.o dev/dev.o dev/ata/ata.o dev/klog/klog.o dev/ramdisk/ramdisk.o dev/tty/console.o dev/tty/keyboard.o dev/tty/tty.o fs/file.o fs/block.o fs/super.o fs/buffer.o fs/pipe.o fs/inode.o fs/fs.o init/main.o lib/kstrncpy.o lib/kpanic.o lib/kprintf.o lib/kvsprintf.o lib/krand.o lib/kmemcpy.o lib/ksrand.o lib/kmemdump.o lib/kstrlen.o lib/kstrcmp.o lib/kstrcpy.o lib/kmemset.o lib/kstrncmp.o lib/bitmap.o mm/mm.o mm/paging.o mm/region.o pm/die.o pm/sleep.o pm/pm.o pm/sched.o pm/signal.o sys/times.o sys/stat.o sys/setgid.o sys/alarm.o sys/shutdown.o sys/kill.o sys/chmod.o sys/ioctl.o sys/umask.o sys/close.o sys/_exit.o sys/ustat.o sys/setegid.o sys/getgid.o sys/fork.o sys/getpgrp.o sys/nice.o sys/chroot.o sys/brk.o sys/syscalls.o sys/ps.o sys/wait.o sys/sync.o sys/unlink.o sys/setpgrp.o sys/signal.o sys/pause.o sys/link.o sys/read.o sys/gticks.o sys/fcntl.o sys/utime.o sys/write.o sys/geteuid.o sys/chdir.o sys/pipe.o sys/getegid.o sys/setuid.o sys/access.o sys/execve.o sys/getppid.o sys/chown.o sys/uname.o sys/lseek.o sys/sem.o sys/open.o sys/seteuid.o sys/getuid.o sys/getpid.o  -o /home/windea/workshop/ricm4/as/nanvix/bin/kernel
```

I have no idea if this will help anyone to understand my issue, but now I think you can have a better grasp of what's going on at least.

Comment: Why do your want to use extern ?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that there is no misspelling of function names and the header with definitions is included before their use in main.c?

Comment: How do you compile (and or link) your code?

Comment: The problem is not related to anything mentioned here. Probably some linker path that needs to be set. Or maybe you are just using Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is not the `extern`, actually it is implicit unless you declare them as `static`

Comment: How do you compile and link the stuff?

Comment: How do you try to build your final program? Compiling the C files is probably not your problem. Linking together is. What is your exact command line you are using?

Comment: functions declared in .h need not use `extern` keyword only variables are required to. Try removing them.

Comment: I made a really more detailled explaination, as the issue seemed to be coming from somewhere else than the extern functions, and I tried to answer all of your questions in there. So, if you wanna take a look, go ahead! :D

Comment: How is the *linking* command line? Please enable verbose output from `make`. The problem is in the linking command.

Comment: I did `make -n` but the result is like 200 lines long, you still want me to paste it in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are compiling only the main.c and not fun1.c, fun2.c and fun3.c

You can try to compile as follows:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c fun1.c -o fun1.o
gcc -c fun2.c -o fun2.o
gcc -c fun3.c -o fun3.o
gcc main.o fun1.o fun2.o fun3.o -o all.out
```

Comment: I made a more detaillled explaination of my project if you wanna take a look. I cannot modify the Makefile, but it's supposed to be perfect (the project is on a kernel used to teach students how kernels work) so there shouldn't be any problem with it.

Comment: @Windea For each file.c you must have file.o. I didn't find for example **semget.o** in the linker command line you gave. so clearly it missing.

Comment: Thanks to you, I kind of understood how the makefile worked (it was just calling multiple other makefiles). And indeed, it wasn't making the object files, because I created a new directory so I just extended the wildcard to the new directory and it works! Thanks a lot!